# How to download a file in c# with a popup asking where to save file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.DownloadFile(pdfFilePath, @"D:\DownloadPastPapers.pdf");
```

I am downloading the pdf file that directly download to specified path but I want to open a popup which asks where to save it (as all normal websites show at the time of downloading)
Its a webfroms asp.net application

Comment: What kind of application would you like the popup to appear in? A web app? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: _I want a [packet of Tim Tams that never runs out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoggSVxghWs)_ . Welcome to SO. Please don't post requirements and like Tim Tims, expect code to magically appear. Any code to show? What research have you done? Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    pdfFilePath = pdfFilePath + "/DownloadPastPapers.pdf";
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.pdf");
    Response.TransmitFile(pdfFilePath);
    Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first popup a `SaveFileDialog` asking for the save path.

Then use this path in your `DownloadFile()`

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog(); 
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory =     Convert.ToString(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); 
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Your extension here (*.EXT)|*.ext|All Files (*.*)|*.*" ; 
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1; 

if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(saveFileDialog1.FileName);//Do what you want here

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
   webClient.DownloadFile(pdfFilePath, saveFileDialog1.FileName");
}
```

Comment: SaveFileDialog isn't even listed as a valid file or namespace

Answer (score 0):

```
private string SelectDestinationFile()
{
   var dialog = new SaveFileDialog()
   {
       Title = "Select output file"
       //--Filter can also be defined here
   };

   return dialog.ShowDialog() == true ? dialog.FileName : null;
}
```

Later

```
private void DownloadFile(string url)
{
    var filePath = SelectDestinationFile();

    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
       throw new InvalidOperationException("invalid file path");

    using (var client = new WebClient())
       client.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
}
```

I hope it helps you.

**P.S.** This is for WPF apps.